# Convert an Array of Images png to Base64

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to convert PNG images, a lot of them to Base64 and then send them over a post request to my server-side application.

I have looked up and I found this function which author has done http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/yvq5y/ here, that do exactly what I want:

```
function convertImgToBase64URL(url, callback, outputFormat){
var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
img.onload = function(){
    var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), dataURL;
    canvas.height = this.height;
    canvas.width = this.width;
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
    callback(dataURL);
    canvas = null; 
};
img.src = url;}
```

I'm using it this way:

```
convertImgToBase64URL(model.cells[i].attrs.image["xlink:href"], function(base64Img){
            // Base64DataURL
            console.log(base64Img)
        });
```

As you can see each cells contains an image, which I need to convert to base64 before sending it over a post request, my question is how can I convert an array of PNG images to Base64 and wait for them to finish and then send my array, I know that this is an ajax request and I can't do this synchronously as it's not very natural to javascript, but I can't seem to find a solution. How this is done properly?

Comment: You could always enter closure hell...

Comment: You need to make sure that `ctx` and `dataURL` are declared with `var` in that "onload" callback.

Comment: You could either use jQuery.Deferred(), or add those base64 strings to an array and send the complete array via ajax. Before sending you may count the  `i` iterator and verify if `array_base64[i] !=null`

Answer (score 0):

The question basically boils down to: [How can I wait for a set of asynchronous callback functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004112/how-can-i-wait-for-set-of-asynchronous-callback-functions)

Since this is plain Javascript code, the waiting part is a bit complicated to implement (there are examples in that answer as well), a pretty easy to use option is from the [answer suggesting using async.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10004155/942390).

Another possibility is to use a Promise library and wrap the function callback in a promise and then wait for all to be fulfilled (usually all libraries have support for such a utility function)

Comment: Foiled by my phone again!

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to submit the form manually after the conversion of data.

```
convertImgToBase64URL(model.cells[i].attrs.image["xlink:href"], function(base64Img){
        // Base64DataURL
        console.log(base64Img)
        $('#img2b64').submit()

    });
```

Comment: from what I understood, the question was asking how to submit the data when *all* are converted

Comment: So u must check about deferred and promise. It's allow you to chain ajax call and then use a single callback when all request are done.