# How wait async ajax requests which was called in different local spaces

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have structure of my programm like this

```
if(some condition){
    $.ajax(...);
}
if(some condition){
    $.ajax(...);
}
doSomething();
```

How I can wait responce of async $.ajax functions before doSomething()? Is it "true way" to use async: false ?

Comment: Setting `async: false` will almost never solve anything. If you need it, it's mostly because of bad design. The solution from A. Wolff should be the prefered way.

Comment: Don't ever use async:false as @smoksnes already said. You might want to take a look at [stackoverflow.com/questions/10004112/how-can-i-wait-for-set-of-asynchronous-callback-functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004112/how-can-i-wait-for-set-of-asynchronous-callback-functions)

Answer (score 2):

You could push these requests in an array:

```
var requests = [];
if(some condition){
    requests.push($.ajax(...));
}
if(some condition){
    requests.push($.ajax(...));
}

$.when.apply($, requests ).done(doSomething);
```