# .every() not waiting for HTTP request

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running an HTTP GET request using the popular node-request module for each item in an array; then running a function at the last item of the array. My code goes like this:

```
const request = require('request');
var arr = ['John', 'Jane', 'Marry', 'Scarlet'];
var x = 0;
arr.every(function (i) {
    x++;
    /*instead of waiting for request, it adds x and moves on making x
    3 when the first request finally runs*/
    request({
        url: 'http://localhost:8810/getLastName?firstName=' + i
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        //execute some code
        if(x==arr.length){ 
            //therefore this function is run for each item in the array.
            // it should run only once per array.
        }
    })
return true;
})
```

I was hoping to achieve this without writing a ton of code therefore keeping my code nice and neat.

EDIT: I'm not trying to run it in order. I don't mind it running in parallel but I'm just trying to trigger a function ***once*** on completion.

Comment: You should use promises. http://blog.slaks.net/2015-06-10/advanced-promise-usage/

Comment: `request()` is async.  It doesn't block.  You have to write your code using promises or callbacks that keep track of when every async operation is done.  Do you want to serialize the requests (one at a time) or run them all in parallel and just know when they are all done?

Comment: I just want to know when its all done so I can run that last function once.

Comment: [How can I wait for set of asynchronous callback functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004112/how-can-i-wait-for-set-of-asynchronous-callback-functions/10004137#10004137)

Comment: Ill give it a shot.

Comment: @WaseemI. - So.  The fact that the array is of unknown length has nothing to do with anything.  You can see the length at any time with `.length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the variable `x`, use the second argument to `every` which is local to the `every` call back function:

```
arr.every(function (i, j) {
 // ...

if (j+1==arr.length) ...
```

While the variable `x` is common to all iterations, each iteration has its own version of `j`, since it is declared within the callback closure. Therefore it will not give you the issue you are experiencing with `x`.

Comment: i is not a number..? i+1 would be NaN.