# why http on end doens't happend at the end of the request

Tags: socket.io, httprequest

hello i don't understand what is going wrong in my code
the array trips line 32 is not fill when i do v.comment = JSON.parse(body_detail).comment at the line 49 and i try to on.emit it after.
I did trips[i].comment too but without success.
my log says it because i do the on.emit() outside the function.
If you have some advice i'll be glad to ear it. thx.

```
    var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var https = require("https");
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('push', (msg) => {
    var options = {
      "method": "GET",
      "hostname": "public-api.blablacar.com",
      "port": null,
      "path": "/api/v2/trips?"+
      "fn="+msg.fn+
      "&tn="+msg.tn+
      "&db="+msg.db+
      "&limit=10"+
      "&locale=fr_FR"+
      "&_format=json",
      "headers": {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "key": "xxx"
      }
    };
    var q = https.request(options, (res) => {
      var chunks = [];
      res.on("data", (chunk) => { chunks.push(chunk) });
      res.on("end", () => {
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        var trips = JSON.parse(body).trips;
        trips.forEach((v,i) => {
          var options = {
            "method": "GET",
            "hostname": "public-api.blablacar.com",
            "port": null,
            "path": "/api/v2/trips/"+v.permanent_id,
            "headers": {
              "accept": "application/json",
              "key": "xxx"
            }
          };
          var q = https.request(options, (res) => {
            var chunks_detail = [];
            res.on("data", (chunk) => { chunks_detail.push(chunk) });
            res.on("end", () => { 
              var body_detail = Buffer.concat(chunks_detail);
              v.comment = JSON.parse(body_detail).comment
            });   
          });
          q.end();   
        }, this);      
        io.emit('pull', trips);    
      });
    });
    q.end();   
  });
});
http.listen(3000, () => { console.log('listening on *:3000') });
 //console.log(body.toString());
```

Comment: Boy you are asking for trouble with multiple overlapping definitions of `q` and `res`.  I haven't studied your code in detail to know if you actually have created a problem with that, but I sure try to avoid that potential confusion.

Comment: FYI, your `.forEach()` executes synchonously, but the async operations inside it finish some time later.  You need to keep track of when all those async operations inside the `.forEach()` are actually done.  There are many possible ways to do that.   See [How can I wait for multiple async operations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004112/how-can-i-wait-for-set-of-asynchronous-callback-functions/10004137#10004137) for ideas on how to do this.

Comment: promise !!! Thx you