# Promise then doesn't work async?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have following problem. I need to return value from REST server. Everything is okey, i am getting what i want, but there is a small problem. Asynchronous is not working and i have no idea why. I will show you my code and result by images.

**Code**

[image: Title]

**And result in chrome**

[image]

Why is it not working as i want to work? Of course, result should have been 
1/2
then 3. Thanks for any help

**js code**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.error = this.getBlockedText();
}
private getBlockedText(): string {
    let customTxt;
    this.proxy.core.getUISettings({}).then(res => {
            customTxt = res;
            console.log('1');
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('2');
    })
    console.log('3');
    return customTxt;
}
```

Comment: Please copy-paste your code instead... This will help us to help you

Comment: Don't post code as image.

Comment: Also, you hide the only interesting part of your code...

Comment: Why are you censoring your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Asynchronous is not working

Yes, it is.

> Why is it not working as i want to work?

Because you want it to work synchronously and it is asynchronous.

> Of course, result should have been 1/2 then 3.

If you want the promise to resolve **then** show 1 **then** show 2 **then** show 3 … you have to put each of them (including the `3`) in `then()` handlers.

At the moment, you've put the `3` straight after the code which **starts** the asynchronous function, so it gets run before the asynchronous function has finished.

Comment: Also, I'd note that the promise itself should be returned instead of a value, which will get defined way too late

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to this
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004112/how-can-i-wait-for-set-of-asynchronous-callback-functions) if you have questions regarding async calls. Last part runs before the async calls so your issue