# oncaplaythrough of multiple videos (grid)

Tags: javascript, video, grid, load

I am trying to figure out a way of playing back videos only after all 4 have loaded to a canplaythrough state. I was thinking of nesting functions to then come to a playClass function like below

```
var classVideos = document.getElementsByClassName("playbackVideos");

playVideos(){
    for(i=0; i<classVideos.length; i++){
        classVideos[i].play();
    }
}

loadVideos(){
    classVideos[0].oncanplaythrough = function(){
        classVideos[1].oncanplaythrough = function(){
            classVideos[2].oncanplaythrough = function(){
                classVideos[3].oncanplaythrough = function(){
                    playVideos();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The loadVideos() function would be called by a play button or eventListener on a seekbar with "mouseup".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)s with [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I wait for set of asynchronous callback functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004112/how-can-i-wait-for-set-of-asynchronous-callback-functions)

Comment: Any examples of how this might work. Never played with promises before.

Comment: From the first link: [Using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), and the duplicate has also some examples with promises - hence the duplicate ;)