# Node.js execute command synchronously

Tags: node.js, synchronization

Hello to all forum members.
I'm pretty new in terms of node js,What I want to do is execute commands synchronously

A simple example:this is my code below.

```
var arr=fun_test(){blah blah blah}
console.log(arr);
```

What actually happens is that I do the second command before the first one,
I will be happy for any help.

Comment: It will depend on the specific modules and operations you're trying to use. While some, especially Node.js' own code modules, offer synchronous versions for I/O operations, it is typical for packages to offer only asynchronous I/O. So, getting used to it and being familiar with options for managing it will be a necessary skill to have with Node.js. A good summary of common options can be found in the answers to "[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)"

Comment: Also [How can I wait for set of asynchronous callback functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004112/how-can-i-wait-for-set-of-asynchronous-callback-functions)

Comment: can you show me example of how could i Wait until function is finished then console.log  with out set time limit.