# How to wait for asynchronous JSZip .forEach() call to finish before running next code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jszip

I have a global variable called 'data' that is being modified inside a forEach loop. However, since the loop is asynchronous, the code does not wait until data is populated before it continues with the code. This is using the JSZip library.

```
let data = [];

await zip.folder("folderName").forEach(async function (relativePath, file) {
            let json = await zip.file(file.name).async("text");
            data.push(json);
            console.log(data.length); // prints increasing numbers
        });

console.log(data.length); //prints 0
// need to do something with data but it is empty
```

How do I wait for the data array to be populated before I continue with the code?

Comment: Looking at the api, `forEach` does not look to be async, so sending a promise to it wont work, its expecting a callback..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I wait for set of asynchronous callback functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004112/how-can-i-wait-for-set-of-asynchronous-callback-functions) and many, many others

Comment: @JJJ not really. Most of those answers and the "many, many others" will suggest using `map()` which is not an option here, or manually iterating the set with a `for` loop, which is also not possible here without making assumptions about the internals of the API.

Comment: I cannot see how map could not be used here.

Comment: @JJJ might want to look at the API before blinding closing as a duplicate then. The return value is not an array, it's an API-specific object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`forEach()`](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/for_each.html) has no return value so it cannot be awaited. You'll have to populate an array of promises from each [`ZipObject#async()`](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_zipobject/async.html) and [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) that array using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to get the results:

```
const promises = [];

zip.folder("folderName").forEach(function (relativePath, file) {
  promises.push(zip.file(file.name).async("text"));
});

Promise.all(promises).then(function (data) {
  // do something with data
});
```

Answer (score 4):

According to JSZip documentation, there's no way to convert [`forEach(callback)`](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/for_each.html) to an array of `Promise`s. So the only way I came up with was to get the number of files and use a counter.

```
const myFolder = zip.folder("folderName");
const numberOfCallbacks = Object.keys(myFolder.files).length - 1;
let counter = 0;
myFolder.forEach((relativePath, file) => {
    // your code. you'd better create a Promise here and add it to an array of promises.
    counter++;
    if (counter === numberOfCallbacks) {
        // everything is done. If you created Promise above, here you can use Promise.all()
    }
});
```

I tested the above code and it worked. Let me know if there's a problem.