# How to use js async/await in mutiple async requests

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise, async.js

I'm using Angular 7, now there is a method(Angular guard CanActivate) that contains some nested http call methods, i need to return data after all nested http call finished.

As below code shows, only after `getCurrentUser()` finished, then return result in `canActivate()`, while now, it always return false because `getCurrentUser()` haven't finished.

```
export class AuthGuard implements  CanActivate{


  constructor(private commonService: CommonService) {
  }

  async canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    console.log('======');
    await this.getCurrentUser();
    return this.hasAccess;
  }

  hasAccess: boolean = false;

  async getCurrentUser(){
    await this.commonService.getToken().subscribe(token => {
      this.commonService.getCurrentUser(param, token).subscribe(o => {
        if(o.success){

          this.hasAccess = true;

        }else {
            window.location.href = '/forbidden.html';
          }
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    });
    console.log("async");
  }
}
```

you can see there are two async methods A,B should be await, and A,B are not parallel, i checked docs about Promise and async/await, didn't find solution.

As await should always follow async, how can i do to let `canActivate()` return result after all the async http call finished?

+++Update

`this.commonService.getToken()` and `this.commonService.getCurrentUser(param, token)` are http call(HttpClient), i tried a lot of solutions but no result.

Answer (score 0):

The Promise.all() method is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi hugojavadi,  can you share the details about `Promise.all()`, i'm new using it. Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: really appreciate your help, i checked your posted docs and found it's a still two layer no matter how many async requests. Just like the doc, method A Promise.all([1, 2, 3]), while in my case, 1 and 2 two layer request that it may need async 2 await 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `async await` and `Promise.all`. In this way you can wait for all your async network request and when all requests have finished, perform some action.

A `Promise.all()` takes an array of promises and wraps them into a single promise. And we already know some nice syntax for dealing with a single promise. We can await it.

For your understanding, take a look at this code sample:

```
let films = await Promise.all(
  characterResponseJson.films.map(async filmUrl => {
    let filmResponse = await fetch(filmUrl)
    return filmResponse.json()
  })
)
console.log(films)
```

I have quoted this example from this article, which can help you to figure out your solution

[How to use async/await with map and Promise.all](https://dev.to/jamesliudotcc/how-to-use-async-await-with-map-and-promise-all-1gb5)

Update:
For your use case you can use like this:

```
async getCurrentUser(){
  await this.commonService.getToken().subscribe(async token => {
    await this.commonService.getCurrentUser(param, token).subscribe(o => {
      if(o.success){

        this.hasAccess = true;

      }else {
          window.location.href = '/forbidden.html';
        }
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  });
  console.log("async");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, while for my case, how can i `Promise.all()` for nested async call 
 
       ```ts
   await this.commonService.getToken().subscribe(token => {
      this.commonService.getCurrentUser(param, token).subscribe(o => { 
```

Comment: use try catch block to handle error as well. Above code won't be able to handle errors @Ankit

Comment: @KDFinal I have updated the answer for your specific need. It will help

Comment: @Ankit  `canActivate()` return result before  `this.commonService.getCurrentUser()` finished, it doesn't wait this async request, do you have any idea?

Comment: @KDFinal Did you wrapped it inside Promise.all()

Comment: in other words,  `getCurrentUser()`shoulld return result until `this.commonService.getCurrentUser(param, token)` finish

Comment: should i use `Promise.all()`?
`async canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    console.log('======');
    // await this.getCurrentUser();
    Promise.all([this.getCurrentUser()]).then(() => console.log('finish'))
    return this.hasAccess;
  }`

Comment: await Promise.all([this.getCurrentUser()]);

Answer (score 0):

`async` and `await` are built on top of promises. Promise is a special object in javascript extensively used to avoid **callback** hell

Also `try` `catch` blocks are important while using `async` and `await` because we need to handle errors as well, incase API fails.

```
hasAccess: boolean;
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise < boolean > {
    this.getCurrentUser();
    return this.hasAccess;
}

async getCurrentUser() {
    try {
        const output1 = await Promise.resolve(fetch(urlOfToken).then(res => res.json())) // if GET call, if POST you can postData('', {})
        const currentUser = await this.postData(
            `URL fetching current user`,
            {
                token: `access token from object ${output} `,
                param: 'any other param'
            }
        );
        // Check in currentUser Object whether response contains user or not
        // If user exists set this.hasAccess = true;
        // IF not set this.hasAccess = false;
    } catch (error) {
        // Error Handling
        console.log(error);
    }
}
// Courtesy MDN
async postData(url = '', data = {}) {
    // Default options are marked with *
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
        cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
        credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
        referrer: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *client
        body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    });
    return await response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}
```

Extra reference on how to use `promises` along with `async` and `await`. Also on how to make parallel, sequence and race API calls

```
const urls = [
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums',
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
];

// BASIC

Promise
    .all(urls.map(url => {
        return fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
    }))
    .then((results) => {
        console.log(results[0]);
        console.log(results[1]);
        console.log(results[2]);
    })
    .catch(() => console.log('error!'));


// async await
// built atop of promises
// benefit is it is easier to make code read easier nothing more promises can get job done actually
const getData = async function () {
    try {
        const [users, albums, posts] = await Promise.all(urls.map(url => {
            return fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
        }));
        console.log('users', users);
        console.log('albums', albums);
        console.log('posts', posts);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Oops!');
    }
}

// for await of
const getData2 = async function () {
    const arrayOfPromises = await urls.map(url => fetch(url));
    for await (let request of arrayOfPromises) {
        const response = await request.json();
        console.log(response);
    }
}


const a = () => promisify('a', 100); // I am making it asynchronous here ; Can be API call or any asynchronus task
const b = () => promisify('b', 1000);// I am making it asynchronous here ; Can be API call or any asynchronus task
const c = () => promisify('c', 5000);// I am making it asynchronous here ; Can be API call or any asynchronus task

const promisify = (item, delay) =>
    new Promise((resolve) =>
        setTimeout(() =>
            resolve(item), delay));

// Parallel

async function parallel() {
    const [output1, output2, output3] = await Promise.all([a(), b(), c()]);
    return `parallel done right: ${output1} ,  ${output2} , ${output3}`;
}

// race

async function race() {
    const output1 = await Promise.race([a(), b(), c()]);
    return `race done right: ${output1}`;
}

// sequence

async function sequence() {
    const output1 = await a();
    const output2 = await b();
    const output3 = await c();
    return `sequenece done right: ${output1}, ${output2}, ${output3}`;
}


parallel().then(console.log);
race().then(console.log);
sequence().then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the above answers and other people's help, i updated my code and now it works.
My update is use `new Promise()` in **getToken()**, **getUser()** instead `await` it, `Promise` has there status(*pending*,*resolved*,*rejected*), once status changed it won't be changed anyway, in that way, once `Promise`'s status changed to *resloved*, it won't be changed and `Promise` will return it's value, else it will error if change to *reject*.

Attach my updated code as below:

**canActivate**:

```
async canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    console.log('======');
    let token = await this.getToken();
    // let hasAccess = await this.getUser(token);
    return await this.getUser(token);
  }
```

**getToken()** and **getUser()**:

```
// return a Promise object and resolve(token)
getToken(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      this.commonService.getToken().subscribe(token=>{
        resolve(token)
      })
    })
  }

  getUser(token: any) {
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.commonService.getCurrentUser(param, token).subscribe(o => {
        if(o.success){

          hasAccess = true;
        }else {
          window.location.href = '/forbidden.html';
        }
        resolve(hasAccess);
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
        resolve(hasAccess);
      });
    })
  }
```

I'm not very familiar with **async/await** and **Promise**, so welcome correction error.